# Filter in left layered navigation not showing in Fresh installed Magento1.9.2.4

Tags: product-attribute, magento1.9.2.4, filtered-nav, product-listing

I have installed **Magento 1.9.2.4**, in which I have not written a single line of code there and not any custom or third party module installed there.

I have just created few categories and products at backend.

When I go category page (product listing page) at forntend, filter are not visible there below category filter.

[image]

There is an attribute **color**, I have assigned it on products.

But this attribute is not visible at frontend. Below are the things which I have checked double and sure about --

1) I have assigned **color** attribute to **Default** attribute set.

2) **color** attribute has **`Use In Layered Navigation`** option set to **`Filterable (with result)`**

3) Have cleared `cache` and `reindex`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Besides the attribute settings, you also need to check each category.
I.E. the category needs to be **anchored**.

While editing the category, go to the Display Settings tab and check that Is Anchor set to **yes**.

possible solutions are

1. Click on category->display setting-> Is anchor set to "Yes".
2. Open attribute and set layered navigation -> yes.
3. If still not working, reindex from system->index management

Comment: thanks@hit's , it worked. Human always do silly mistakes :)

Comment: great! welcome, yeah you are right Shashank. :)